# azure activity log collection for multiple resource group

Tags: python, azure

I am able to collect the azure log from a particular resource group using the curl command

curl -s -k -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer %s" -H "Content-Type: application/json" 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%s/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2015-04-01&$filter=eventTimestamp%%20ge%%20%%27%s%%27%%20and%%20eventTimestamp%%20le%%20%%27%s%%27%%20and%%20resourceGroupName%%20eq%%20%%27%s%%27&$select=operationName,status,resourceId,subscriptionId)

My problem is resourceGroupName this take only one resource group name. I want multiple resource group name here. I there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the current supported syntax for Azure REST API call to get the Activity logs.

[image]

[Documentation Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activitylogs/list#uri-parameters)

Hope this helps.